# Custom loss with conditional return value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I want a loss function with this regularization: for each prediction, if the predicted point has norm lower than 0.9 or greater than 1, I want to apply the regularization.

So I wrote this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

ret = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

n = tf.norm(y_pred, axis = 1)
intern_circle_distance = n - 0.9        
return tf.where(tf.logical_and(tf.greater(intern_circle_distance, 0),
                               tf.less(intern_circle_distance, 0.1))
                        ret,
                        ret*2)
```

When I use this in the model.compile, an error is returned:

Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1 for 'loss_71/Hyper_loss/Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?], [], [].

I tried the loss outside keras' enviroment and it seems to works.
For example this:

```
a = tf.constant([[-1.0, 1.5]])
n = a - 1
K.eval(tf.where(tf.logical_and(tf.greater(n, 0)),
                               tf.less(n, 2)),
                a, a*2))
```

returns me the Tensor [-2., 1.5]

Why it works outside keras loss function and doesn't work inside keras loss function?
How can it works inside keras loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keras.losses.mean_squared_error` gives you a scalar number, the mean of all the squared errors. If you want to change the error calculation per example, then do something like this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = tf.squared_difference(y_true, y_pred)
    n = tf.norm(y_pred, axis=1)
    intern_circle_distance = n - 0.9
    diff_reg = tf.where((intern_circle_distance > 0) & (intern_circle_distance <0.1))
                        diff, 2 * diff)
    return tf.reduce_mean(diff_reg)
```

Comment: I change the syntax in the first argument to `tf.where` for convenience, but that is the same as what you had.

Comment: @NooneBug Glad it helped. Please consider upvoting and/or marking the answer as accepted if you feel it solves your question.

Comment: @NooneBug That's fine. You can mark answers to your question as accepted though (green tick), if you want, to indicate it was solved.